# スプレッドシートのシートを複数作成したいのですが、応答なしで固まる

Tags: google-apps-script

スプレッドシートのシートを複数作成したいのですが、応答なしで固まるためご教示ください。
待機を何度か押下すれば、問題なくシートの作成はできます。

シート作成の処理が重くなるみたいですが改善策がわかりません。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

```
let mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var templateSheet = mySheet.getSheetByName('マスタ'); 

for(i=0;i<50,i++){
    mySheet.insertSheet(日報+i, 2+i, {template: templateSheet}); 
}
```

Comment: 大量のシートを一気に作成しようとして固まっているように見えます。シート数を減らしてみたり、スリープをかましてみるとよいかもしれません。参考: [How to use Utilities.sleep() function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142109)

Comment: このような場合は、Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp)の代わりにSheets APIを使用すると解決できる可能性があります。例えば、大きなデータをSpreadsheetで扱う場合、setValuesやgetValuesを用いると同様の問題が発生し、これをSheets APIに切り替えることで解決するケースがあります。